# Xcode6 - Swift (PDF viewer and ENSideMenu)

Tags: swift, ios8

I am building an App that has PDF's local to be used offline. I have used [ENSideMenu](https://github.com/evnaz/ENSwiftSideMenu) and table views to dynamically point to and present the PDF's in a UIWebView. Here is the code for the PDF view:

```html
var pdfLoc = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("PDF_file", ofType:"pdf")!) //replace PDF_file with your pdf die name
 var request = NSURLRequest(URL: pdfLoc);
 self.pdfWebView.loadRequest(request);
```

This is my Nav Controller:

```
import UIKit

class MyNavigationController: ENSideMenuNavigationController, ENSideMenuDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sideMenu = ENSideMenu(sourceView: self.view, menuTableViewController: MyMenuTableViewController(), menuPosition:.Left)
        sideMenu?.delegate = self //optional
        sideMenu?.menuWidth = 180.0 // optional, default is 160
        //sideMenu?.bouncingEnabled = false

        // make navigation bar showing over side menu
        view.bringSubviewToFront(navigationBar)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - ENSideMenu Delegate
    func sideMenuWillOpen() {
        println("sideMenuWillOpen")
    }

    func sideMenuWillClose() {
        println("sideMenuWillClose")
    }
```

This is my table view controller:

```
import UIKit
import QuickLook


class FirstStepsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

        var pdfs = [FirstStep]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var newPdf = FirstStep(name: "First People To Call List", filename: "firstpeople")
        pdfs.append(newPdf)

        newPdf = FirstStep(name: "Top 5 Things To Do In An Emergency", filename: "top5")
        pdfs.append(newPdf)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pdfs.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("pdfCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...

        var currentFirstSteps = pdfs[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = currentFirstSteps.name
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0;

        // Retrieve an image
        var myImage = UIImage(named: "pdf")
        cell.imageView?.image = myImage

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        return "First Step"

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat{
        return 50
    }

        var secondScene = segue.destinationViewController as DisplayFirstStepsViewController

        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let selectedPdf = pdfs[indexPath.row]
            secondScene.currentFirstSteps = selectedPdf
        }

    }


}
```

And this is my UIWebView within a UIViewController:

```
import UIKit

class DisplayFirstStepsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var currentDocument: UIWebView!

    var currentFirstSteps : FirstStep?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var pdfLoc = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource((named: currentFirstSteps!.filename), ofType:"pdf")!)
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: pdfLoc!);



        self.currentDocument.loadRequest(request);


        navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

This is my MenuTableViewController:

```
import UIKit

class MyMenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var eachSection = ["Home","First Steps","Communication","Equipment & Supplies", "Computer Systems","Critical Vendor Contact Info"]
    var selectedMenuItem : Int = 0
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Customize apperance of table view
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64.0, 0, 0, 0) //
        tableView.separatorStyle = .None
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.6)
        tableView.scrollsToTop = false




        // Preserve selection between presentations
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: selectedMenuItem, inSection: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: .Middle)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return 6
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL") as? UITableViewCell



        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "CELL")
            cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            cell!.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

            cell!.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0;
            let selectedBackgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell!.frame.size.width, cell!.frame.size.height))
            selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.4)
            cell!.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView

        }

        cell!.textLabel?.text = eachSection[indexPath.row]

        return cell!
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 50.0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        println("did select row: \(indexPath.row)")

        if (indexPath.row == selectedMenuItem) {
            return
        }
        selectedMenuItem = indexPath.row

        //Present new view controller
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil)
        var destViewController : UIViewController
        switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home") as UIViewController
            break
        case 1:
            destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstSteps") as UIViewController
            break
        case 2:
            destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Emergency") as UIViewController
            break
        case 3:
            destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EmergencyEquip") as UIViewController
            break
        case 4:
            destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Computer") as UIViewController
            break
        case 5:
            destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Critical") as UIViewController
            break
        default:
            destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home") as UIViewController
            break
        }
        sideMenuController()?.setContentViewController(destViewController)
    }
```

My problem is that the menu loads, I click on a "page" (Table View Controller) then click on the table view cell to then be taken to the UIViewController with the UIWebView of the PDF. When I click back to the table, the menu is no longer functional. I get the following error:

Could not resolve the absolute path of the old directory.

Any ideas how to resolve this? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Did you use a navigation controller ? And what's your code this isn't enough.

Comment: Yes I did. This is my Nav controller:

Comment: Hopefully that gets you what you need. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thank you! I fixed it. That was my problem. I didn't have the menu attached to the first view of each 'scene'. Not sure if that makes sense at all but your question actually made me think of it from another perspective and got it resolved. I can't thank you enough!!!

Comment: What question?? This "Did you use a navigation controller ?".

Comment: Some posted but removed a question asking "Which was first?" That got me to realize I have different nav controllers for each "set of scenes" and each was first. They were not each connected to the menu however. I added an IB action to each nav controller and it worked.

Comment: I delete it because I thought I was a noob and I could determine the first view from the code